# Add simple field column to the posts screen

Tags: posts, screen-options, plugin-simple-fields

I know that `manage_posts_columns` is the hook for managing the column in post screen.

I can add a column with following code,

```
// add new column hook
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_new_column_in_posts');
function add_new_column_in_posts($columns) {
    $columns['premium'] = 'Premium';
    return $columns;
}
```

My question is, how can I feed the `simple_field` value for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column
Just use the WP built in action called "manage_posts_custom_column" and in callback check for the correct column and add simple_field value with the function *simple_fields_value* :

```
            add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'add_new_column_data_in_posts', 10, 2 );

            function add_new_column_data_in_posts( $column, $post_id ) {
                switch ( $column ) {
                    case 'premium' :
                        echo simple_fields_value("simple_field_slug", $post_id); 
                        break;
                    }
            }
```